# Are Java App of Android App compatible with Java SE?

Tags: java, android

My question is: Java applications of Android app are compatible with Java SE?

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know if my answer is what you asked for**

As far as I know Android itself currently supporting Java SE 7 and subset of SE 8. 
For later Java SE version I don't see any official docs on Android.com. 
That I got from official doc:

> Android Studio 3.0 and later supports all Java 7 language features and
>   a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version.
>   Check here: [Java 8 Support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

You can check this SO post for some more info about your query. 
[Does Android Studio 3 support Java 9 for Android development? If so, what features of Java 9 are supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47627603/9932194)