# Error: package org.threeten.bp.format does not exist

Tags: java, android

```
private void setStartDateAndEndDate() {
        TextView startDateTextView = mStartDateView.findViewById(R.id.fixtures_total_count);
        startDateTextView.setText(SelectedDateTimeHolder.getSelectedStartDate().getDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM dd yyyy")));
        TextView endDateTextView = mEndDateView.findViewById(R.id.fixtures_total_count);
        endDateTextView.setText(SelectedDateTimeHolder.getSelectedEndDate().getDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM dd yyyy")));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the old lib with [this one](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

The package org.threeten.bp refers to [this project](https://www.threeten.org/) which is now closed.

Aim of the project was to provide updates to the JDK8 as stated [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)

The availability of the same functionalities is not guaranteed as Android SDK [supports only partially the complete JDK8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230781/relationship-between-os-version-api-level-and-java-version)

Comment: did this answer your question?